# Inverted Index with MapReduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to implement an inverted index for the following problem: I am given a directory with X amount of files, I need to produce output of the following format:

```
word : totalCount : [ (file_name, file_count) (file_name, file_count) ...]
```

So for example, we could have:

```
dog : 200 : [(file1, 30) (file2, 43) ....]
```

I implemented a job which works for each individual document and outputs the number of times each word occurs in each document. However, I am confused with how I should proceed now in order to obtain the count for all the documents.

If I have a directory with 10 documents, and my input is the path to the directory itself, how do I execute the 10 jobs for each of the documents? Also, how do I set up the job which takes the output from the 10 individual jobs? I know how to implement the logic for the reducer, however I'm not sure how to set up the job configuration itself to make sure this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in single map-reduce job. Pass all the input path to your map-reduce job.

Do it as follows.

**Map output** : key- Word,file name  value- count

**Partitioned** : Based on word only

**Group partition** : Again based on Word only

Now in recuder you will have input like

```
Dog,file1,1
Dog,file1,1
Dog,file2,1
Dog,file2,1
```

iterate over the key(we have taken key as word only based on group compactor) dog. and take count for each file and later add it and take total count.

Comment: If I pass the whole directory to my map-reduce job, how will the mapper know which document it is currently dealing with? How would I split the input data into the individual documents?

Comment: First of all map-reduce will process all the files in your directory. it will launch map-reduce based on your input split. To get the file name inside your map method use String fileName = ((FileSplit) context.getInputSplit()).getPath().getName();

Comment: how would I ensure that most of the input going into the first mapper is from document 1, followed by document 2 etc. The way I am checking the number of occurrences of each word in the mapper is by sorting the input alphabetically, the problem with this is that I would like to only sort the input from doc_1 alphabetically first before even touching doc_2.

Comment: why you want to ensure? why you need sort in mapper? I am not getting what exactly you want. can you give some example. As I said in mapper only write <key=<word,file name> , value=count>. Sorting will happen in sorting phase of map-reduce job. in group compactor take only word part of key.